# Alarm manager in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have created simple alarm app. It works fine but, if i change time of device manually then my alarm doesn't work....

This is my code:

```
    Calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    //c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,1);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,15);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MyAlarmService.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(HomeActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Doesn't work means whats happening?

Comment: Hi @PareshMayani : If i set my alarm to 5 pm and than i manually set time of my device to 5 pm then alarm didn't work.

Comment: It will not work, you need to add a reciever to set the alarm again..on date and time zone change then alarm got reset so use this  <receiver android:name=".AlarmInitReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: set the time just before 2-3 minutes and waits for the alarm ring.

Comment: Im also this problem.This question and comment of Maneesh is very usefull to me

Comment: @Maneesh Plase add your answer as an answer so that this question doesn't show up in the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Adding the answer from comment to here]

You need to add a receiver to set the alarm again..on date and time zone change then alarm got reset so use this

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmInitReceiver"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" /> <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" /> 
</intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```